# Storage setup for large files

Tags: hardware, storage, network-attached-storage, local-area-network, files

I need to store over 200TB of data (all types, biggest being video files) and be able to access it over a local network. The files will be accessed for editing or searches. I don't need versioning, but a setup that would keep me safe from harddrive failures would be nice.

Right now the content is on different harddrives, some external drives, some regular. I don't exclude the possibility of buying new/extra drives if necessary. If they will ever be exposed to the web, it wont be to the public, but just a couple of people.

I have no idea what to buy to make this happen. I see some NAS solutions over the internet like this http://www.bestbuy.com/site/a/2266043.p?id=1218317764591&skuId=2266043 but the storage is not enough, plus it doesn't seem to be scalable.

What do you recommend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want scalability, check out GlusterFS, it's a distributed file-system. If you create a storage cluster, GlusterFS can make it seem like a single file-system. It has support for software-based RAID 0 (striping) and 1 (mirroring).

Comment: This sounds good but before I get to that I'm more interested in the actual hardware config

Answer (score 0):

I do large scale FC SAN work and that sort of volume is nothing for most mid-level storage kit. Obviously it's not free and I do understand the instinct to cut costs/corners by just scaling up the free roll-your-own code such as FreeNAS etc. but it's the actual chassis and links that is likely to hold you back going that way.

Presumably you need this available 99.9%+ so you'll need due controllers/heads at least. Do you need file or block level access and if the latter from how many client machines over what protocols? What about speed, both bandwidth and overall IOPS? What about snap capabilities, replication, backup? Do you have a budget in mind? Or any preferred vendors/models.

Comment: My purpose is more basic. A couple of users (3-4) will access video/image files for editing. Macs and PCs. Right now I'm attaching one drive at a time to a regular enclosure. I just want them to browse the network instead of moving hardrives all the time :)  Each file has around 25 GB and should be edited directly over the network, without being copied locally (if possible, have no idea). No need for replication and would consider backup a raid setup. I would not want to go over 1.5k (excluding drives) but I have no idea how close or far I am with that estimation. Can go over if needed.

Comment: PS: file level access is probably what I need

Comment: Ah, now we're definitely in my area! You're going to struggle for that budget to be honest. What editing application are they using right now and what file format/s? It'll probably be very slow over 1Gbps NAS protocols. The more I think about this the less I think you can do this for the budget in fact, adding a zero would be more like it actually. Maybe look at some of the super micro boxes but you'll need at least 2 disk controllers, probably more, plus external chassis etc.

Comment: Just looked at supermicro, you're still talking many times your budget even for the most basic parts sorry.